# Binding on key withing a custom class

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, binding, dictionary

Is it possible to bind on a `Key` within a custom class like it is possible with a `Dictionary`?

I can bind to a `Dictionary` with this binding:

```
"Binding MyDictionary[MyKey]"
```

But I don´t want to use a `Dictionary` but a custom class like this:

```
public class DataGridField :  INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [Required]
    [Key]
    public string Key { get; set; }

    private object value;
    public object Value
    {
        get
        {
            return this.value;
        }
        set
        {
            this.value = value;
            this.OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }
}
```

Now I want to access objects of this class within a `ObservableCollection` the same way I do it with the `Dictionary`.
Is there some way to achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can, but you have to implement [indexer property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2549tw02%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
public class DataGridField
{
    public string this[string index]
    {
        get { return this.Key; }
        set
        {
            this.Key = index;
        }
     }
 }
```

**Edit:**

But if you are interested in having Dictionary with INotifyProperty/CollectionChange implementation, you can use [ObservableDictionary](http://blogs.microsoft.co.il/blogs/shimmy/archive/2010/12/26/observabledictionary-lt-tkey-tvalue-gt-c.aspx)

Comment: the indexer property was exactly what I was looking for! Thank´s!